# Reset number scheme in latex using enumerate

Tags: numbering, enumerate

A very simple question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. I have a numbering scheme using `\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}`

However I want the level 2 numbering scheme to also be Arabic:

level 1: 1

level 2: 1

Instead of

level 1: 1

level 2: (a)

How can I do this?

I've tried just using nested `\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far?

Comment: It's not a roman numeral!

Comment: Fixed. See above

Answer (score 1):

Nesting `enumerate` environments is the correct way to do this. But you also need to redefine how the second level enumerate labels are displayed. You can do this by putting the following command into your document preamble (between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`:

```
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
```

The labels for enumerations are via `enumi` through `enumiv` `\theenumX` is responsible for formatting the number and `\labelenumX` calls `\theenumX` and puts any additional formatting around the number on the enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

It can easily be done using the command `\setlist` from the package `enumitem`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*.}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item An item in the first level.
    \item Another item in the first level.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item An item in the second level.
        \item Another item in the second level.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```